# Python face_recognition dataset quality

Tags: python, face-recognition

I´m construction a dataset with more than one image for each person for python [face_recognition](https://face-recognition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package. It will add a classifier on top of the bultin model. See also this example: [face_recognition_knn.py](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/face_recognition_knn.py). here is my code:

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils import paths
import face_recognition
import pickle
import cv2
import os


# grab the paths to the input images in our dataset
print("[INFO] quantifying faces...")
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images('dataset'))

# initialize the list of known encodings and known names
knownEncodings = []
knownNames = []

# loop over the image paths
for (i, imagePath) in enumerate(imagePaths):
    # extract the person name from the image path
    print(f"[INFO] processing image {i+1}/{len(imagePaths)} -> {imagePath}")
    name = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]

    # load the input image and convert it from BGR (OpenCV ordering)
    # to dlib ordering (RGB)
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # detect the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding boxes
    # corresponding to each face in the input image
    boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb,
        model='hog') #can be cnn

    # compute the facial embedding for the face
    encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb, boxes)

    # loop over the encodings
    for encoding in encodings:
        # add each encoding + name to our set of known names and
        # encodings
        knownEncodings.append(encoding)
        knownNames.append(name)

# dump the facial encodings + names to disk
print("[INFO] serializing encodings...")
data = {"encodings": knownEncodings, "names": knownNames}
f = open('encodings.pickle', "wb")
f.write(pickle.dumps(data))
f.close()
```

Then, I try to identify these people with this code:

```
import face_recognition
import pickle
import cv2
import numpy as np
import requests
from datetime import datetime

# load the known faces and embeddings
print("[INFO] loading encodings...")
data = pickle.loads(open("encodings.pickle", "rb").read())

def processa_imagem(url):
    # load the input image and convert it from BGR to RGB and returns file with cofidence
    image = cv2.imread(url)
    if image is None:
        print(f'Image not found: {imagem}')
    #image = np.array(image, dtype=np.uint8)
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # detect the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding boxes corresponding
    # to each face in the input image, then compute the facial embeddings
    # for each face
    print("[INFO] recognizing faces...")
    boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb,
        model='hog')
    encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb, boxes)

    # initialize the list of names for each face detected
    names = []

    # loop over the facial embeddings
    for encoding in encodings:
        # attempt to match each face in the input image to our known
        # encodings
        ##  ATTENTION! the ideal is face_recognition.api.batch_face_locations but i dont have a GPU 
        matches = face_recognition.face_distance(data["encodings"],
            encoding)
        name = "unkown"

        # check to see if we have found a match
        if max(matches) > 0.7:
            # find the indexes of all matched faces then initialize a
            # dictionary to count the total number of times each face
            # was matched
            matchedIdxs = [i for (i, b) in enumerate(matches) if b]
            counts = {}

            # loop over the matched indexes and maintain a count for
            # each recognized face face
            for i in matchedIdxs:
                name = data["names"][i]
                counts[name] = counts.get(name, 0) + 1

            # determine the recognized face with the largest number of
            # votes (note: in the event of an unlikely tie Python will
            # select first entry in the dictionary)
            name = max(counts, key=counts.get)

        # update the list of names
        names.append(name)


    # loop over the recognized faces
    for ((top, right, bottom, left), name) in zip(boxes, names):
        # draw the predicted face name on the image
        cv2.rectangle(image, (left, top), (right, bottom), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        y = top - 15 if top - 15 > 15 else top + 15
        cv2.putText(image, name, (left, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            0.75, (255, 0, 0), 2)
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H%M%S%f")

    #file_path = f'static/face-{current_time}.jpg'
    file_path = f'face-{current_time}.jpg'

    cv2.imwrite(file_path,image)

    return (file_path, ', '.join(names))
```

On my dataset, I´ve added, on average, about 10 photos of each individual. The script uses `face_recognition.face_distance` and it works well to recognize someone **in** the dataset.

**The problema is that, when I use it with someone that OUT. For these people, sometimes I still get about 0.90 higher confidence false positive results.**

Some of the pictures in dataset are low quality. Maybe that´s the reason? Should I change my approach, using more detailed photos (2 or 3) and maybe encoding them with [jitters](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/wiki/Face-Recognition-Accuracy-Problems)?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: I don't know how this lib works but I'd suggest you to try adding photos of people out of your targeted database. When a model will predict one of those extra people you will treat it as negative.

Comment: Since it's about theory more than coding, this question might be better fore the [datascience.se] stack site

Comment: I added some more info for clarification. It actually is a classifier on top of a model, not a model by itself. I´ll look into to data science

Comment: I have been working with face_recognition recently and have discovered a few variables relating to the output results of face_recognition (real-time).  The quality and size of the dataset per known_face is crucial, obviously if the dataset is too small(<10 faces/person) or poor quality(size<250x250 or overall capture of features) the result will be unreliable.